# Array slicing based on filter

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, filter, slice

I am trying to filter an array of 20000 rows and 70 columns by a particular column. I want to copy the whole row to another array if the value in column 14 is "Hard". I came up with a very simple implementation and tried using it but Excel went Not Responding everytime crashed eventually. Then I added DoEvents in the loop so that excel does not crash. My code looks as follows for now. It would help a lot if the community could help me optimize it. It is taking way too much time right now.

Is there some other function I can use to slice the array, instead of Index, that would be working faster?

```
Dim arr_all() As Variant
Dim arr_Hard(1 To 20000) As Variant
Dim arr_Soft(1 To 20000) As Variant
Dim arr_Travel() As Variant



arr_all = wsCopyTo.Range("A2:BR20000").Value
m = 1
n = 1
For i = LBound(arr_all) To UBound(arr_all)

    DoEvents

    Select Case arr_all(i, 14)

        Case "Hard"

            arr_Hard(m) = Application.Index(arr_all, i)
            m = m + 1

        Case "Soft"

            arr_Soft(n) = Application.Index(arr_all, i)
            n = n + 1

    End Select


Next i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Solution

1. **Sort the items in the original Worksheet** by the Hard/Soft column (desc or asc no matter). If you can't sort for some reason then copy the original worksheet to a new one.
2. **Find the row where Hard/Soft items end** - simply count the number of Hard or Soft with `COUNTIF`, whichever comes first, and get the required ranges of cells `FROM` and `TO` for both `Hard` and `Soft` items
3. **Use the `wsCopyTo.Range("A[FROM]:BR[TO]").Value`** to simply copy the part of `Hard` and `Soft` to array `arr_Hard` and array `arr_Hard`

Comment: This got the runtime from around 1 second per row to 2-5 seconds for 15k rows. Thanks!